# wget a link with google redirect

Tags: wget

Got a page full of downloads but all using https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.$$$/*.pdf&....

I can download using http://www.$$$/*.pdf direct but there are 50+ files.  Anyway to avoid this?  Can wget do it?  I tried but it only download the links as it is under [www.google.com/](http://www.google.com/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep -P` to filter out the real links and either add as input-file (`-i`) to `wget` using process substitution:

```
wget -i <(grep -Po '[?&]q=\K[^&]*' links)
```

---

However, I guess that the embedded URL is URL encoded, then you need a step to unquote:

```bsh
urldecode() { [ $# -eq 0 ] && str=$(</dev/stdin) || str="$@";  : "${str//+/ }"; echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"; }
wget -i <(grep -Po '[?&]q=\K[^&]*' links | urldecode)
```

or with `python`'s `urllib.parse.unquote`:

```bsh
wget -i <(python -c '
import re
from urllib.parse import unquote
with open("links") as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    url=re.search("([&?]q=)([^&]*)", line)
    print(unquote(url.group(2)))
')
```

(of course you could use `python` to replace the `wget` part also ...)